# mask work for id but not for class

Tags: javascript

hi i have a problem with my javascript code it works for input by id but i wat to use it on class element. I do not know what is i am doing wrong any idea? I paste my code
i want to mask time on my input

```
 function maska(inputName, mask, evt) {
     var text = document.getElementsByClassName(inputName);

     try {

         var value = $(text).val(); //text.value;

         // Jeśli ktoś naciśnie dela lub backspace to czyszcze inputa
         try {
             var e = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
             if (e == 46 || e == 8) {
                 $(text).val() = ""; //text.value = "";
                 return;
             }
         } catch (e1) { }

         var literalPattern = /[0\*]/;
         var numberPattern = /[0-9]/;
         var newValue = "";
         for (var vId = 0, mId = 0; mId < mask.length; ) {

             if (mId >= value.length) 
                 break;
             // Wpada jakaś inna wartość niż liczba przechowuje tylko ta dobra wartosc
             if (mask[mId] == '0' && value[vId].match(numberPattern) == null) {
                 break;
             }

             // Wpadł literał
             while (mask[mId].match(literalPattern) == null) {
                 if (value[vId] == mask[mId])
                     break;

                 newValue += mask[mId++];
             }
             var godzina = value.substr(0, 2);
             var minuty = value.substr(3,4);

             if (minuty > '59' || godzina > '23') {
                 break;
             }
             else
                 newValue += value[vId++];

             mId++;
         }
         text.val() = newValue;
         //text.value = newValue;
     } catch (e) { }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById` returns a single `DOMElement` while `getElementsByClass` returns an array of elements. To allow for both, you could have one function that accepts a `DOMElement` and two functions that find the elements, one for id and one for class:

```
function maska(elem, mask, evt) {
   try {
         var value = $(elem).val(); 
    // blah blah, rest of the function
}

function maskById(id, mask, evt) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   maska(element, mask, evt);
}

function maskByClass(class, mask, evt) {
    var element_list = document.getElementsByClass(class);
    for(var i = 0; var i < element_list.length; i++) {
        maska(element_list[i], mask, evt);
   }
}
```

But you would be better off using the jquery selector combined with `.each` , which always returns results as a set/array, regardless of selector type.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` returns a single element, which your code is written to handle.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements.  You need to loop over them and process them each individually.

Comment: Could You give me some example how to do it ?

Comment: the same way you loop over anything else: with `for` and `.length`.  you have a similar loop in your code already  :)

Comment: but how get count of class element classname.length ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you use `getElementsByClassName` and then use jQuery features? 
try `$('input.' + inputName)`

Comment: this is what i was trying to change to get working with class sory for that

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns a single element, while `getElementsByClassName` returns a *collection* of elements. You need to iterate over this collection

```
function maska(inputName, mask, evt) {
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName(inputName);

    try {

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var value = text[i].value;

            // Jeśli ktoś naciśnie dela lub backspace to czyszcze inputa
            try {
                var e = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
                if (e == 46 || e == 8) {
                    text[i].value = "";
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (e1) { }

            var literalPattern = /[0\*]/;
            var numberPattern = /[0-9]/;
            var newValue = "";
            for (var vId = 0, mId = 0; mId < mask.length; ) {

                if (mId >= value.length) 
                    break;
                // Wpada jakaś inna wartość niż liczba przechowuje tylko ta dobra wartosc
                if (mask[mId] == '0' && value[vId].match(numberPattern) == null) {
                    break;
                }

                // Wpadł literał
                while (mask[mId].match(literalPattern) == null) {
                    if (value[vId] == mask[mId])
                        break;

                    newValue += mask[mId++];
                }
                var godzina = value.substr(0, 2);
                var minuty = value.substr(3,4);

                if (minuty > '59' || godzina > '23') {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    newValue += value[vId++];

                mId++;
            }
            text[i].value = newValue;
        }
    } catch (e) { }
}
```

Comment: Notice, that I also replaced a part of code where you had `return;` when backspace or delete is pressed. I replaced it with `continue;` to let the script iterate over next elements, not just exit the function.